# Option to choose reply from address on mail.app in Lion

Tags: mail.app

My default position is to stay within the OS X ecosystem unless their is a compelling reason to use use a 3rd party product. Gmail (with Sparrow) has long been keeping me from using mail.app on my desktop, but I'm thinking it's time to reconsider. I'm hoping someone can answer this to save me doing the work just to find out - Can I choose which of my accounts to reply from or am I limited to the address it was sent to ?

Comment: Brilliant thanks guys for quick and detailed responses ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's no problem, you can have multiple accounts, and you get to choose which is the default, as well as reply from a different account on a per-mail basis by choosing from a drop down.  You can even choose different SMTP servers from the same mail account, allowing you to (for example) route the same account through your own SMTP server as email address X, or choose to route it through GMails own SMTP server which allows you to transform your sender address in the Gmail Web App Settings.

Answer (score 2):

1. On the fly in the reply dialog:

   [image]
2. Set default in the preferences:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you configure multiple accounts, or even different aliases for the same account, you can reply to messages from any account/alias combination, even different from the one that recieved the mail.